# suplotting two data frame columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to subplot two columns of a data frame using matplotlib. Here is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
df[['Percentage variance (%)', 'Net weight (%)']].plot(kind='bar')
```

The end result I'm aiming for is to see one set of color bars for 'Percentage variance (%)', and another set of color bars for 'Net Weight (%)' both on the same figure.

For some reason matplotlib ignores the plt.subplot(2,1,1) commmand and won't place the bar graph onto the designated subplot.

Has anyone ever encountered this and know of a fix/workaround?

Comment: If you want the two columns on the same figure, i.e. same plot(if this is what you mean), why do you need subplot()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me.
You need to specify in which subplot you want to plot using the `ax` keyword of the dataframe's `plot()` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Percentage variance (%)' : [10,20,30],
                   'Net weight (%)':[22,16,18] })
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
df[['Percentage variance (%)', 'Net weight (%)']].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @VikramJosyula If this answered your question then you may accept this solution, such that the question does not appear as unsolved in the list anymore.